# How can I build a Docker Image without accessing the Docker Hub or External Sites?

Tags: docker

I'm sitting behind a firewall at work and cannot connect to the usual external sites to get started with Docker. Is it possible to build a Docker Base Image from an .iso file or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create a base image from scratch:
https://docs.docker.com/articles/baseimages/

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer Andy. Option 1 on that link appears to also use some sort of external Repo that appears to be blocked from where I'm. Option 2 uses the Docker Hub as far as I can tell. Any other options?

Comment: I've never done it myself, but you should be able to create a root file system based on the Linux system where you're running. You could use something like [rsync](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_rsync) or [tar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23986453/1452016) to grab create an image based on your current machine. Then use `docker import` to pull in the tarball.