# Create docker base image for a linux iso image

Tags: docker, coreos

How can i make a docker base image from a coreos iso image?
i tried tar -cf the iso image to tar file, but it's failed.
docker import ... just for .tar archive file?
thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274088/how-can-i-make-my-own-base-image-for-docker

Comment: @Matazure - Did you find any good solution to this ? I am in the same boat as you but in my case its ubuntu iso and not coreos iso.

Answer (score 1):

It is untypical to go from a  full OS image (even when it is a small OS) to a docker image. Actually CoreOS is more intended to run docker instead of beeing the appliance of a docker image.

What base image you want to use and why? You might not need any if you pack your app with some dependencies (and run it on a Docker install in coreOS).

I guess you would be able to extrace the ISO (some packers can do that) and remove the parts docker does not need (like the kernel), but as I said you should avoid it.

Comment: eckes - Suppose I have an application that runs many commands on server. In order to run commands properly, I have changed many permissions in the operating system. 

Now, is it appropriate to make the image of whole operating system containing application OR is it appropriate to make the docker image of application itself and keep the settings in dockerfile ? TIA

Comment: It depends, but the advantage of a docker file is, that you can repeat and version control it. Typically you make your own base images if you use them for multiple projects and you set up something which is large or takes long. But you try to avoid using them for hand made tweaks. (and not needing to modify os parts is even better!). Of course if you are not into repeatable building software and do not have the time to script it, a once fumbled image is easier.  @v1h5

Comment: And if you have a deeply integrated application which needs all kind of system services and interacts with them, I guess a normal virtualized application is a better alternative. @v1h5.

Comment: Ok, I see. 
I have an application and I am really got stuck with the decision whether to make docker image of application only or make docker image of whole Operating system running that application.

Comment: can you have a sneak peak in my question. I think you can help. 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742967/how-to-make-docker-image-of-host-operating-system-which-is-running-docker-itself)