# How to create a base CoreOS image and build custom parent images based on it

Tags: docker, coreos, chromium-os

Currently most docker images at https://registry.hub.docker.com/ are ubuntu based. I would like however to run a somewhat leaner base image, i.e. CoreOS. Und than build custom packages/images on top of it, i.e. erlang and yaws. 
Is there some easy or standart way to do this?
Using the cros_sdk I could modify an image, but I'm not sure if I could just build few additional gentoo packages and package them as a parent image.

I guess I could somehow put the upstream portage tree into the CoreOS dev env/chroot, emerge the packages I need and import the binary packages into a new parent image. Are there instructions of how this could be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create docker base image for a linux iso image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214715/create-docker-base-image-for-a-linux-iso-image)

Answer (score 0):

There are some cool posts out there telling you how to optimize docker images. Whatever, I am not getting your point wanting to build a own coreos image. I understand you want a lean image. Here you go.

```
docker pull base/archlinux
docker pull scratch
```

Further here is a nice article I found on scratch http://blog.xebia.com/2014/07/04/create-the-smallest-possible-docker-container/