# How to make docker image of host operating system which is running docker itself?

Tags: docker

I started using Docker and I can say, it is a great concept.
Everything is going fine so far. 
I installed docker on ubuntu (my host operating system) , played with images from repository and made new images.

`Question:`

I want to make an image of the current(Host) operating system. How shall I achieve this using docker itself ? 
I am new to docker, so please ignore any silly things in my questions, if any.

Comment: I took it away because I am doing something else and can't go look, but I would be VERY surprised if you couldn't find the answer to this on Google. Probably on StackExchange somewhere.

Comment: The thing I am trying to do is a little bit tricky and google would not be perfect match as I already tried googling this. 
Next to google, S.O has always been my preferred choice. 

Well, I would be happy if you could solve my problem.
TIA

Comment: Docker doesn't work that way.  Docker lets you build things up in layers, starting from scratch or starting from someone else's image.  It doesn't let you start from a complete machine and create an image from that.

Comment: You said "someone else's image". I understand the concept of "base image" in docker. Is it possible that I have this "base image" as my operating system's image ?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this? Create an image/backup of a system and make a docker image so that you can replicate the system with it's configurations anywhere? That would be incredibly useful.

Comment: @v1h5- If you find a way of doing this please reply to your question as how to make such a tar file and steps after that?

Answer (score 19):

I was doing maintenance on a server, the ones we pray not to crash, and I came across a situation where I had to replace sendmail with postfix.

I could not stop the server nor use the docker hub available image because I need to be clear sure I will not have problems. That's why I wanted to make an image of the server.

I got to this thread and from it found ways to reproduce the procedure.

Below is the description of it.

We start by building a tar file of the entire filesystem of the machine (excluding some non necessary and hardware dependent directory - Ok, it may not be as perfect as I intent, but it seams to be fine to me. You'll need to try whatever works for you) we want to clone (as pointed by @Thomasleveil in this thread).

```
$ sudo su -
# cd /
#  tar -cpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/dev --exclude=/sys /
```

Then just download the file into your machine, import targz as an image into the docker and initialize the container. Note that in the example I put the date-month-day of image generation as image tag when importing the file.

```
$ scp user@server-uri:path_to_file/backup.tar.gz .
$ cat backup.tar.gz | docker import - imageName:20190825
$ docker run -t -i imageName:20190825 /bin/bash
```

IMPORTANT: This procedure generates a completely identical image, so it is of great importance if you will use the generated image to distribute between developers, testers and whateever that you remove from it or change any reference containing restricted passwords, keys or users to avoid security breaches.

Comment: Here to add that the tar command lead to `tar: /: file changed as we read it` error for me and I had to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/37993307/13875968 for making the tar file.

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure to understand why you would want to do such a thing, but that is not the point of your question, so here's how to create a new Docker image from nothing:

If you can come up with a tar file of your current operating system, then you can create a new docker image of it with the [docker import](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#import) command.

```
cat my_host_filesystem.tar | docker import - myhost
```

where `myhost` is the docker image name you want and `my_host_filesystem.tar` the archive file of your OS file system.

Also take a look at [Docker, start image from scratch](https://superuser.com/questions/669118/docker-start-image-from-scratch) from superuser and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18278948/107049) from stackoverflow.

If you want to learn more about this, searching for `docker "from scratch"` is a good starting point.

Comment: `I'm not sure to understand why you ........`

Actually I am running a host system and there are many things configured on this machine. Now, I wanted to practice docker, so did the setup on this machine itself. 
As I was practicing docker, I thought to make an image of this machine too. 
Out of curiosity, this question got its inception. 

Well, I tried your command but the syntax of `import` expects second argument to be a URL.

Comment: ...and I want to test configuration changes to a production machine without affecting production.