# Creating a Docker Image for a Github Project

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a [GitHub project](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine), (that I am working with (I didn't create it)), called OpenRefine, which I would like to *encapsulate* in a Docker image, such that other people can then pull that Docker image from the "Docker Hub" and have OpenRefine installed on their fundamental interactive Docker entity, viz. Image.

I want to then upload it to a repository that I can share with others.

It would be good if it had a name and not a crazy hash value.

---

Is it that I just create a "docker file" a text files with a `git clone` command?

but then how to upload that to a repository such as the docker hub? I just put that text file there?

Something like

FROM ubuntu

MAINTAINER :/ WTF?!

RUN git clone blah

CMD what here?

[image]

---

This seems like a very basic issue but the information is not readily accessible in the [Docker provided tutorials](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/), nor is there a definitive answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274088/how-can-i-make-my-own-base-image-for-docker), but those are indisputably excellent resources for a very complicated way to make a terminal output "*Hello World*".

Comment: do you want to publish an image that will have the latest code from the master branch or do you just want to publish an image for your releases?

Comment: it doesnt have to have the latest code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While Sergius' answer isn't wrong, additional ways to do this would be through a Dockerfile https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/. This way you can either include a Dockerfile in your github project and build that image to put up on docker hub.  Or you can create a dockerfile that pulls your project from github, runs any necessary build steps and then push that to docker hub.

In either ways you would need to build the image from the dockerfile with

`docker build -t <name of image> <OPTIONS> <build context>`

and then you would use `docker push` to push the image.

For a Dockerfile outside of your project:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get install git && \
git clone <your git repo> && \
<additional bash commands for building your project>
CMD <command to run your project> # Can also use ENTRYPOINT in certain cases
```

Comment: is there like a standard one for just an ubuntu image with a github project using gitclone?

Comment: If you create a repository on the [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) and link it to your github repository, building and publishing your image is just one click away

Comment: You'd need to include a dockerfile in your github project in that case Thomasleveil

Comment: @Thomasleveil that's not really a useful comment, could you explain how?

Comment: I'll add an example dockerfile for what you want

Comment: it's not *my* github project, it's an open source project that use to be managed by google, but i want to create a docker image with it to share with others so that we can all start from the same thing, you know?

Comment: wow. that's it? and how to put that to the docker hub repo then?

Comment: Yeah sure, who owns it isn't important but in that case you'll probably have to use the Dockerfile outside of the project unless you submit a pull request to add it.

Comment: ah, and how to name it. those hash names are too crazy

Comment: Like I said, `docker build` will build it.  You use -t to tag the image with a name, so `docker build -t <your username>/<project> <directory with Dockerfile` will build it. Then `docker push <name you just tagged>`

Comment: Similar to CMD however ENTRYPOINT allows additional arguements to be appended

Comment: does it take parameters as the other do? or just write `ENTRYPOINT`

Comment: ENTRYPOINT takes similar parameters as CMD

Comment: do you write comments in a docker file with `#`?

Comment: yes, see the link in my answer, it pretty much has everything you'd need for a dockerfile.

Comment: ok cool, that's great. thank you very much. my last question though is, for the CMD, should I now try to make an ubuntu VM and figure out what are the commands needed to start that programme, like, should I `cd` to the directory blah blah blah to start it? for me it would just be enough to have the git clone there for someone to build you know?

Comment: Well whatever is the command that is used to have the project run, as you would on a host system, that is what you have for `CMD`. And to be clear, docker is a container and therefore uses the host's kernel and is not a VM.  And a docker container needs to have something that will run in the foreground as `CMD` so not a daemon, docker can daemonize for you if you choose to do so.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't build, I took a screen shot of the error. I think its something to do with git clone on ubuntu NEVERMIND: just gotts do this `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git-core`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but you can try to fetch some basic docker image, which is suitable to run your application. Build your application there and use "docker commit" to get new image, which will contain that basic image with your application.

Answer (score 1):

There are already [plenty](https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=openrefine&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&starCount=0&pullCount=0) of Docker images for OpenRefine hosted on the Docker Hub.

Why don't you take example on one of their Dockerfile? [This one](https://github.com/SpazioDati/docker-openrefine/blob/master/Dockerfile) seems to be the most popular.

Comment: that is a good call for sure, but also I was just kind of interested in how to do it. but or sure this is useful, thank you. I upvoted this answer