# Building docker image with angular 2, jupyter and typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, docker, dockerfile, jupyter

I want to write an interactive tutorial to teach a team how to use Typescript and Angular 2, but I don't want everyone to install Jupyter.

So, I want to build a docker image that has everything needed.

This is my Dockerfile so far, but I am not certain where to copy the package.json from [Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) so `npm install` will find it, do the installation and have Jupyter find it.

```
FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook

MAINTAINER Jupyter Project <jupyter@googlegroups.com>

USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends && \
    apt-get install -y npm nodejs nodejs-legacy wget locales git \
    fonts-dejavu \
    gcc && apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN npm install --save jupyter-js-plugins    

USER $NB_USER
```

I want to add this [plugin](https://github.com/jupyter-attic/jupyter-js-plugins) from github for Typescript.

Another option is to just copy the files to the docker image, but where would they be copied in order to be found by Jupyter?

Comment: `ADD` can pickup from url which is github in your case. Or curl with Run or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189877/creating-a-docker-image-for-a-github-project) should be of help.

Comment: @Rao - I may try your idea as I ran into a problem where the plugin isn't installed, but everything is loaded.  I may just need to build my own docker container and not start with one where Jupyter is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the package.json anywhere as long as you set the WORKDIR before running NPM install.

```
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

The *Dockerfile* you're extending from [uses `/home/$NB_USER/work` as `WORKDIR`](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/base-notebook/Dockerfile#L85). The env variable `NB_USER` is set to `joyvan` in the [base *Dockerfile*](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/base-notebook/Dockerfile#L39)

If you copy your files like this

```
COPY . /home/$NB_USER/work/
```

you should be fine.

I'm not sure how easy it would be to override the env variable, because it is already used when building the images. You're probably better off to just define your own `WORKDIR` in your *Dockerfile* like [@JayChase mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355394/834).