# Unique Process Permissions Linux

Tags: c, linux, process, permissions

Is there a way to give a process on Linux based systems unique permissions in C? I basically want to restrict a process (launched by a host, like an event handler) from editing any files outside it's working directory, and creating sockets and such.

Would the only way to do it is to have a host process create a new user for each process it spawns and destroy the user afterwards?

Comment: It might be overkill, but this sort of thing can be handled with `chroot()`.

Comment: The danger is that most of the possible mechanisms require root privileges to effect the change.  You can look up `chroot()` — but be aware that it is tricky to create an appropriate environment for a `chroot()` program; you can look up BSD 'jails'; you can consider simply setting the real and effective UID and GID to a user/group that can't change anything outside the directory (but note that it will still be able to read publicly accessible files, such as `/etc/passwd`).

Answer (score 2):

The standard answer to this is `chroot`, which sets the process's root directory (and that of its children) to be the given directory.

However, if you want a better answer allowing you to isolate all aspects of the process and not just its file system, look at the `unshare` system call (wrapped in a modern `glibc` as a function). This is how containers are built.

Comment: Do I need root permissions do an `unshare` call?

Comment: This http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html implies not for `CLONE_FS`. You will need root (more accurately `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`) for some of the other `unshare` calls. Personally I've not used `CLONE_FS` without others.

Comment: Also note technically `chroot()` requires `CAP_SYS_CHROOT` rather than root or `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`, though normally they come together.

Comment: Would LXC be a thing worthy looking into?

Comment: `lxc` under the hood just uses the `unshare` system call. It's going to be heavier weight than your question implies the need for as you are going to need a complete container copy of the OS - not just one process. If you want that, the lightest weight solution is Docker (http://docker.io/)

Comment: I'm confused now, as Googling taught me that Docker uses LXC?

Comment: `lxc` is used both for the kernel capabilities (in that sense `unshare` is part of `lxc`) and for a set of command line userspace tools (which is what I thought you meant). My understanding is Docker uses the former but not the latter. See http://linuxcontainers.org/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989306/what-does-docker-add-to-just-plain-lxc http://lxc.sourceforge.net/man/lxc.html

Comment: Will `unshare` be sufficient to block malicious code?

Comment: It depends what kind of malicious code. Malicious code that exploits a kernel vulnerability may still succeed. Malicious code that exhausts resources (e.g. disk I/O, memory) may still succeed unless you use `cgroups` or similar to control them.

Comment: Well, I understand that due to a weakness in the kernel a program might still succeed exploiting the system, but at that point it's beyond my control anyway. I might go with `unshare` and control groups then. That seems to create a pretty secure container. Just can't figure out how `unshare` works. I know it sets up new namespaces, but what to do once you've done that?

Comment: Run `init` or a new process or whatever you want. You might also look at http://openvz.org/

Answer (score 1):

You could use old [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) techniques to switch your process to the `nobody` uid and `nogroup` gid. Theses ids are designed to make a process unable to write any files (except inside all-writable directories).