# What would be pros and cons of using Docker Vs Vanilla LXC?

Tags: docker, lxc, btrfs

I have mostly been an LXC guy running Vanilla LXC with BTRFS,and was wondering what would be the advantages & disadvantages of replacing this with Docker (I know Docker has features like Versioning,Sharing containers e.t.c) ?

Is it a matter of ease of deployment of apps Vs Performance ? How does BTRFS compare with Dockers AUFS ? I'd be glad if anyone has something to share regarding filesystem/IO performance or benchmarks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice explanation what Docker adds to plain LXC, or what it added, before LXC was replaced by libcontainer:

[What does Docker add to just plain LXC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989306/what-does-docker-add-to-just-plain-lxc)

Comment: I went through that post,but didn't see much information on IO performance.May be i should run my own tests in a Vanilla LXC container with BTRFS backend Vs a Docker with AUFS backend.